# No mapping between account names and security IDs was done - Install SQL Server MDS Workflow Integration Service

Tags: sql-server, mds

I try to create custom workflow by following article in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/develop/create-a-custom-workflow-master-data-services.

I try to run InstallUtil Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe, but it failes. I wonder why.

I have specifed as servername\mds_workflow_service user when prompted during installation. I have just for case reset password to make sure that password is correct. The user have read and execute rights to the \bin folder. What could be wrong?

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin>InstallUtil Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe
Microsoft (R) .NET Framework Installation utility Version 4.7.2053.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Running a transacted installation.

Beginning the Install phase of the installation.
See the contents of the log file for the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe assembly's progress.
The file is located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.InstallLog.
Installing assembly 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe'.
Affected parameters are:
   logtoconsole =
   assemblypath = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.exe
   logfile = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Master Data Services\WebApplication\bin\Microsoft.MasterDataServices.Workflow.InstallLog

An exception occurred during the Install phase.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: No mapping between account names and security IDs was done

Answer (score 0):

Solved by enterering service account in format in .\mds_workflow_service